# how can show all table in db in sql dataSource in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I work asp.net and use "aspnet_regsql" for manage user and role .. but i have a problem with work 'data source'.
in 'data source' only show views in database and all table hidden.

I want to know is how the table will be displayed in the list.

please see 2 image in comment.
all table and data source configuration

Comment: "http://i.stack.imgur.com/O6B7G.png".
"http://i.stack.imgur.com/NzB70.png"

Comment: Do not post links to image with your code. It is a lot easier for us if you post the actual code text in your question

Comment: yes.i can solve my problem with code!! but i like now how can config dadasource.

Answer (score 0):

All tables in your database are asp.net created tables, they don't show up in the list of available tables, try adding your own table to the database and see if it shows up there.